# What RHSA, RHEA and RHBA stands for in the RedHat Erratas?

Tags: unix

Do you know what does RHSA, RHEA and RHBA stands for in [RedHat Errata](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata) ?

Comment: So we don't have a good public doc for this (at least that I can find) so I'm putting this on my todo list.

Answer (score 3):

Red Hat categorise advisory notices as relating to Security, Enhancement, and Bug-Fix.

Answer (score 1):

RHEA = Red Hat Enhancement Advisory, these can ONLY contain enhancement fixes (e.g. new features).

RHBA = Red Hat Bug Advisory, these contain bug fixes, and can optionally also contain enhancements, essentially bugs outrank enhancements for reporting purposes.

RHSA = Red Hat Security Advisory, these contain security fixes, and can optionally also contain bugs and/or enhancements, essentially security issues outrank bugs/enhancements for reporting purposes.

The identifying "name" of an RHEA/RHBA/RHSA is the advisory type, the year, identifying number (simply sequential starting at 1) and a version (in case they ever get an update), e.g. "RHSA-2015:2594-1".

Answer (score 0):

I've added an authoritative knowledge base article "Explanation of RHSA, RHBA, and RHEA advisories" that answers:

- What are RHSA, RHBA, and RHEA advisories?
- What happens if an RHEA or an RHBA is found to have fixed a security flaw?
- How does advisory numbering work?

It's available to the public at: https://access.redhat.com/articles/2130961

Comment: Meld your two answers into one please.

Answer (score -1):

RHSA = RedHat Security Announcement

RHEA = RedHat Enhancement Announcement

RHBA = RedHat Bug-fix Announcement

I think.